# how to send message to channel with discord.js, but only have certain users see it?

Tags: discord.js

I want my bot to be able to send messages to a user in a text channel. However, I was wondering if there was a way to make it so that only one person can see it? I don't want to use PM's.

For example, having something like this would be nice

```
client.on("message", msg => {
  msg.channel.send("hi! only you can see this", msg.author.id)
});
```

something like this would nice, where `msg.author.id` is the user that gets to see the message in the channel. Or even an array of discord ids

EDIT: btw, I am using Discord.js

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible, unless you disallow certain users to see the channel as a whole.